# SQL script for Custom mail body from 2 un-related tables

Tags: sql, email

[View Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHJuL.png)I am working on a tool wherein we have to configure a view to send out the custom email notifications to the customers.

I have a view name:
**webNotification_Mail_LiqAmt_Workflow** which stores email details like

Then I have another table from where I need to bring in the amount which is to be mailed to the customers based on their projects and other parameters.
[enter image description here][2]
I do not need email setup because it is already taken care. I need to pass the amount in the email body so basically I need to get the amount in 'messsge' column of the above view (webNotification_Mail_LiqAmt_Workflow)

I cannot think of a way to built this logic as both the tables are un-related.
Please help.

Design of the view:

```
**CREATE VIEW [dbo].[webNotification_Mail_LiqAmt_Workflow] 
AS 
  SELECT ID,
         Event, 
       EmailFrom, 
      Subject, 
         Message,


'NoReply@xyz.com'        AS EmailTo,
         '123@rte.com' AS EmailBCC
  FROM   dbo.webWorkflowNotification_LiqAmt**
```

I would need custom amounts in the message column based on the parametrers.The view that from where I need the Amounts looks like:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [LIQAMTID]
      ,[Project_Name]
      ,[Startup]
      ,[Business_contact_Name]
      ,[Business_Contact_Email]

      ,[Sum_Liq_amt]
  FROM [webLiqAmt_Mail_Notification]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my grasp of the situation I guess what you are looking for is a cross join.By using cross join you could add the two unrelated tables and then later exploit them for your use. I am giving and example,

```
 SELECT username,password,dob,address
   FROM basic_details
   CROSS JOIN login
```

where username and password belong to login, and dob and address belong to basic_details.
OR
You can use cartesian product of the two tables.

```
SELECT * FROM basic_details, login
```

This would result in M * N rows.
Hope it helps.

Comment: No I am not looking for cross join or cartesian product. Unique rows. Editing the questions witht the structure of view